# "Unable to determine a Message or payload parameter on method

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-batch

I have a Spring Integration Messaging Gateway to call SI routes from a (Spring) Batch.
The gateway has a dozen methods; most of them call simple outbound-gateway's to reach external services and work well by passing method parameters to SPEL expressions in the gateway definition.
Now, one particular method has to pass a String to a more complicated route defined as a chain.

The java code for the call looks like this:

```
    businessCase = gateway.retrieveCaseInformation(caseId);
```

The gateway class has this signature for the method:

```
    BusinessCase retrieveCaseInformation(@Payload String caseId);
```

The XML definition for the gateway has this:

```
    <int:method name="retrieveCaseInformation" request-channel="retrieveCaseChannel"/>
```

The chain has a Transformer as first step / entry point:

```
    <int:chain input-channel="retrieveCaseChannel">
        <int:transformer ref="retrieveCaseDataTasklet"
                         method="caseIdToFindCaseByCriteriaRequest" />
```

And finally the method has this signature:

```
    @Transformer
    public FindCaseByCriteriaRequest caseIdToFindCaseByCriteriaRequest(@Payload String caseId) {
        ...
    }
```

Now for this particular assembly and all combinations of annotations (or lack of) I have tried, I get the same error:

```
    Encountered an error executing step step4 in job XXXXX
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to determine a Message or payload parameter on method [public abstract com.example.Gateway.retrieveCaseInformation(java.lang.String)]
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:92)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper$DefaultMethodArgsMessageMapper.toMessage(GatewayMethodInbboundMessageMapper.java:340)
```

Comment: Sounds like you are using wrong `@Payload` class. What is that? And what is your Spring Integration version and Spring Framework version, please ?

Comment: Thanks! That is information I should have provided from the start indeed. Spring core 4.3.7.RELEASE; Spring Integration 4.3.8.RELEASE.

Comment: The snippets above use org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload ; on your suggestion I retried with org.springframework.annotation.Payload but it is deprecated, and I get the same error at the end.

Comment: Hm... any chances that you can provide a simple project on GitHub to let us to play with?